# PL/SQL extract columns from text file

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, plsql

I have a text file with multiple rows.  I want to select a substring from the same position of each row with PL/SQL.
How can I do that?

Example:

This is my text file:

```
ABCDEFGHI
JKLMNOPQR
```

I want to extract column 2-4 on each row using PL/SQL so my result should be like this:

```
BCD
KLM
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options to work with files in Oracle, depending on what your goals are.

**1st Option**

Assuming that all you want to do is to read the file and afterwards do some additional processing

1)Read the file with `UTL_FILE` 
http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS72681

2)
Use the `substring` function to extract columns 2-4

e.g `select substr('ABCDEFGHI',2,3) from dual;`

**2nd Option**

if you are inserting directly from the file into a table and all you need is formatting I suggest you tu use *SQL Loader* 

e.g.

```
load data infile 'data.csv'
append into table mytable
fields terminated by ","
(
str "substr(:str,2,3)",
)
```

**3rd Option**
If you want to access directly the file in SQL and use it -for example in a view-, then you probably  could profit from *External Tables*
http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-ACF1D3AA-1D61-4682-AEC5-42C944756E12.htm#SUTIL1357

Answer (score 0):

1) Firstly you need to create an Oracle Directory for Oracle user who will read a file Or give permission for existing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY file_dir AS '/your/directory/';
```

Permissions:

```
GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY file_dir TO YOU_USER;
```

2) Copy file to your '/your/directory/' folder

3) Run code, something like this:

```
    Create or Replace PROCEDURE Readfile is
    fileForRead UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    line VARCHAR2(200); 
    BEGIN
    f := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(file_dir ,'your_file.txt','R');
      IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(fileForRead) THEN
        LOOP
          BEGIN
            UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(fileForRead,line);
            IF line IS NULL THEN
              EXIT;
            END IF;
            line := substr(line, 2,3);
      END LOOP;
      COMMIT;
      END IF;
     END;
/
```